# Task Execution and wait for tasks to finish: Java

Tags: java, multithreading, task

There is a generic queue of tasks where new tasks get added. I want to write code that will create more work in terms of tasks  by adding them to the queue. The task that added the work to the queue will wait for all tasks to complete by polling the queue.

What would be the best way to implement it using Java.  I was thinking of something on the lines of Simple threads by implementing a runnable interface and make it run in an infinite loop and sleep in between, wake up to see if there is any progress. If the progress is happening, keep on looping, if it has completed break out of the loop. Is there any other good and performance efficient way to implement this ?

How the tasks complete?
The tasks are submitted to a Queue. The Queue is polled by an executor and it runs the tasks.

What i want to do?
Poll that queue to see if the task has completed or is still executing.

Comment: You could have a look at `Future`s http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html#futures

Comment: Only if you know the number of tasks, you can also use a `CountDownLatch` in order to block code until all tasks have completed. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html

Comment: The tasks are submitted to a Queue. The Queue is polled by an executor and it runs the tasks. So essentially i want to poll that queue to see if the task has completed or is still executing

Comment: I would make the executor that polls the queue notify the thread when the queue is empty.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing here, may be a rough sketch of a work queue. You could enqueue processes for asynchronous processing, wait for a notification of completion, and then terminate. This works, but there are new concurrency tools available. I recommend reading the [Java Concurrency Lesson](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

The new model for concurrency allows you to separate the concurrency concerns from the thread via tasks, `Runnable` and `Callable` and the `ExecutorService`. Rather than working directly with threads and building your own thread pool try to let the `Executor` do the heavy lifting for you.

```
...
ExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
....
```

You may hand tasks, in the form of Runnables and Callables, to the ExecutorService and receive in return Future objects which may be used to monitor the task's progress.

```
Future<String> f = executor.submit(new Foo());
....
class Foo implements Callable<String> {

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return "Bar";
    }
}
```

You may use an ExecutorCompletionService to monitor the completion of tasks for you :

```
CompletionService<String> cs = new ExecutorCompletionService<String>(executor);
Future<String> f = cs.submit(new Foo());
... // Let's say you've added TASK_COUNT tasks
for (int i = 0; i < TASK_COUNT ; i++ ) {
    try {
        String str = cs.take().get();
        if (str != null) {
            System.out.println(str); //Handle the result of the Callable
            continue;
        }
    } catch (ExecutionException ignore) {}
}
```

now you've received a result per callable, you can clean up your tasks using the `Future f` object you received earlier with `cs.submit(new Foo())` , by invoking

```
f.cancel(true)
```

on each task. And finally, don't forget to clean up your executor with

```
executor.shutdown();
```

There is a lot more to concurrency than this, but I believe that the above illustrates a means to meet your needs. I'd recommend reading the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) as well.

Answer (score -1):

Use `java.util.concurrent.Future` and a `java.util.concurrent.CompletionService`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Fork/Join](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) framework from java 7